# NSNotFound not working with NSUser default

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

As I am storing one Integer value into `NSUserDefaults` aas its used at many places. At first time its working fine but while i close my application and again open it I am check that user already selected any option in past feom `NSUserDefaults` stored value but I am failed in that

Some thing is wrong in my case

Here is my code for checking Integer value is there in **userdefault** :

```
NSInteger selectedBusinessUnit = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"selectedUnit"];

if ( selectedBusinessUnit != NSNotFound){
    //go to direct main screen.
}else {
 // load Business unit screen for selection.
}
```

But its always found value even i am deleting app and reinastall it.

Always my selected value is **0**.

Let me know what is my silly mistake here.

**Edit:**

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:sender.tag forKey:@"selectedUnit"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

THNAKS .

Comment: friend can you show your setInteger:forKey code?

Comment: I am sure you are doing something wrong while setting value.

Comment: Consider that `NSNotFound` is a valid integer value. It's not equal to `nil` or *key is missing*. As stated in an answer `integerForKey` returns 0 if the key is missing. Is a different tag assigned to the `sender` at all (default is also 0)?

Comment: So there is only one way to store my integer and check its nil or not with NSNumber replecment ??

Comment: You could *register* your integer with the default value of `NSNotFound`. This value is considered until it changes the first time. Then your logic will succeed.

Comment: I didnt get you can you explain more. Thanks for your quick reply.

Comment: I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously there is a misunderstanding: `NSNotFound` is not equal to *key is missing*, it's a valid integer value.

The easiest way to keep your logic is to register the key-value pair with `NSNotFound` as the default value.

As soon as possible (`applicationDidFinishLaunching` or earlier) write

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSDictionary *defaultValues = @{@"selectedUnit": @(NSNotFound)};
[defaults registerDefaults:defaultValues];
```

That means `NSNotFound` is considered as default value until it's overwritten the first time. The 3 lines must be executed every time the application launches. If the app is reinstalled the default value is taken again.

Now you can use your logic in the question.

PS: You don't need to `synchronize` after writing. The framework does that periodically.

Comment: Thaks for your Answer let me check.

Comment: Awesome! !! Its working perfect and learnt new thing that we can register default value like this many many thanks Vadian.

Comment: @BhaviDev  I didn't understand why you are getting stored value zero each time, even my code is working in the my case.

Comment: @vadian could you explain ?

Comment: @Mukesh Explain what?

Answer (score 1):

The default value for integer is 0, according to the documentation:

> -integerForKey: is equivalent to -objectForKey:, except that it converts the returned value to an NSInteger. If the value is an
>   NSNumber, the result of -integerValue will be returned. If the value
>   is an NSString, it will be converted to NSInteger if possible. If the
>   value is a boolean, it will be converted to either 1 for YES or 0 for
>   NO. If the value is absent or can't be converted to an integer, 0 will
>   be returned.

if you want to check if a key exists in NSUserDefaults use:

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"selectedUnit"] != nil)
{
...
}
```

Comment: But my value is in integer not in form of Object so will it work with intergerForKey also ??

Comment: You can try and save it as NSNumber instead of NSInteger, and then use intValue on the resulting object instead, just save like this: setObject:@(integer) and it will give you a better result

Comment: Yes i know that i can use NSNumber insted on integer but what my questio  is is there any way to check integer have value or not like NSNotFound work with integer value.

Comment: NSNotFound is eventually an Integer, your problem is that the default integer value is 0 and not NSNotFound, even though you use an integer as your input value to NSUserDefaults, you can still use objectForKey to check if it exists, if it does, an NSNumber will be returned, otherwise nil

Answer (score 0):

`NSUserDefaults` storage only object, `NSNumbers`.
I think the problem in conversion from `NSNumber`, which you stored to integer in method `integerForKey`.

**Another case** - may be you forgot a synchronize `NSUserDefaults`.

Answer (score -1):

You can set object like

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults setObject:@(yourIntegerValue) forKey:@"yourIntegerKey"];
[userDefaults synchronize];
```

and you can check like this

```
NSNumber *integerValue = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"yourIntegerKey"];
if (integerValue) {
   //
}
```

Comment: How can we store Integer direcly like that this will not work as you are setting object and passing Integer.

Comment: `NSUserDefaults` has dedicated `setInteger:forKey` and `integerForKey:` methods. No need to use `object`.

Comment: You can set integer to object like @(integer) or [NSNumber numberWithInt:0] or [NSNumber numberWithInteger:0]

Comment: Of course i know, we can set set integer to nsuserdefaults. But default integer value is zero. I believe this answer is better...